# How to fix the router-outlet in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

***home-routing.module.ts***

```
const routes: Routes = [
  Shell.childRoutes([
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, data: { title: extract('Home') } },
    {
      path: 'history',
      component: HistoryComponent, data: { title: extract('History Logs') }
    }
  ])
];
```

***home.module.ts***

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NgxsModule.forFeature([TemperatureState]),
    CommonModule,
    TranslateModule,
    CoreModule,
    SharedModule,
    HomeRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent,
    HistoryComponent
  ],
  providers: [
  ]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

***home.component.html***

```
<h1>Home</h1>
    <a routerLink="/history">History</a>
    <div>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
```

What I'm trying to do here is to display the history when click the link below the Home.
It work but the Home text will be remove.

Answer (score 0):

Remove that router-outlet i.e., **`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`** in **home.component.html** and give a try.
I think your are using 2 router-outlet that's why your are facing issues
According to you logic your should have just 1 router-outlet.

Comment: it doesn't work the HOME, it changing a component instead the HOME should be remain and on the below the Home, the data of history will be displayed when clicking the history link

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample for you here on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/routing-example-lijdvs?file=app/routing.module.ts). Click on `Page1` on the header of sample. You will see it display the content of both `homeComponent` & `Page1Component` together.

So, if you want display the history below the content of the home try this:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  Shell.childRoutes([
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, data: { title: extract('Home') }, children: 
     [
        {
          path: 'history',
          component: HistoryComponent, data: { title: extract('History Logs') }
        }
     ] 
    },
    
  ])
];
```

**app.component.ts**

```
<h1>Home</h1>
<a routerLink="/home/history">History</a>
<div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Path `history` has to be child route of `home`

```js
//app.routing.ts

import {
  NgModule
} from "@angular/core";
import {
  Routes,
  RouterModule,
  PreloadAllModules
} from "@angular/router";
import {
  FutureComponent
} from "./future/future.component";
import {
  HistoryComponent
} from "./history/history.component";
import {
  HomeComponent
} from "./home/home.component";

const routes: Routes = [{
    path: "home",

    children: [{
        path: "history",
        component: HistoryComponent
      },
      {
        path: "future",
        component: FutureComponent
      },
      {
        path: "",
        redirectTo: "future",
        pathMatch: "full"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: "",
    redirectTo: "home",
    pathMatch: "full"
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules,
      onSameUrlNavigation: "reload"
    })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

```html
<!--Home.html-->
<div>
  Home
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a [routerLink]="['home/history']">History</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a [routerLink]="['home/future']">Future</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

Complete working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fy8yuo)